# How to connect to SSH with '@' character in username

Tags: ssh

I was given login credentials to a server and there is an `@` character in my username.  How can I make an SSH connection in my terminal?

**username:** foo@domain.com
**host:** domain.com

I've tried

```
$ ssh "foo@domain.com"@domain.com
$ ssh foo@domain.com -l domain.com
```

Nothing is seeming to work.

Any help?

Comment: Depending what OS you're using you can just connect in to the domain and enter a username once you join. Not optimal but still a solution.

Answer (score 25):

If the username is foo@domain.com you can try this:

```
$ ssh 'foo@domain.com'@domain.com
```

Comment: The quotes only escape the path from the shell. In this instance, as far as `ssh` is concerned it would be identical to `ssh foo@domain.com@domain.com`

Answer (score 11):

I just created a new user on my system called `foo@domain` and I could ssh into it perfectly well with just

```
ssh foo@domain@server
```

If for whatever reason that does not work for you, you can also do

```
ssh 'foo@domain'@badabing
```

or

```
ssh 'foo\@domain'@badabing
```

Comment: The quotes only escape the path from the shell. In this instance, as far as `ssh` is concerned, either suggestion would be identical to `ssh foo@domain.com@badabing`

Answer (score 3):

Whoever gave you the login credentials may have made a mistake. Have you tried just: `ssh foo@domain.com`?

Comment: I've voted you up, and I'm going to leave it, but there are instances where this is possible, and the first `@` can be replaced with a `+`.

Comment: Wow. I never knew that '@' was a valid username character... but then I never tried to use a username with an '@' in it.

Comment: It depends on the environment. I've seen with some virtual hosts this set-up. It's not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your username is foo so you should try: `ssh foo@domain.com` that will prompt you for the password.